# Multiple location to reference location dimension

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure-sql-database, data-modeling

I am trying to map values associated to my location dimension - dimension seen below:

| LocationID | Country | State | City | Zip Code | Longitude | Latitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USA | NY | Manhattan |  |  |  |
| 2 | USA | NY | Yonkers |  |  |  |
| 3 | USA | NY | Buffalo |  |  |  |

I am receiving transaction data where multiple regions may be identified as a value. For example, I will get a value for city as such: Yonkers/Manhattan and Manhattan/Yonkers.

Transaction Data example:

| TransID | From City | To City |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yonkers/Manhattan | Manhattan/Yonkers |
| 2 | Manhattan/Yonkers | Yonkers/Buffalo |

The rule is that the **first city** in the 'From City' should be used when linking to the location dimension and the **last city** in the 'To City' should be used when linking to the location dimension. The final result should be as followed:

| TransID | From City ID | To City ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |

I would really appreciate any assistance on this.

Comment: How do you handle city names existing in several states, e.g. Venice?

Comment: @jarlh I use zip codes in the dimension table. Apologies, left it out as I thought it would not impact the question.

Comment: Maybe this helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60089058/split-string-based-on-position-and-delimiters OR this can also be a helpful approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried and got the required results by using inner join on the dimension table and transaction table. Use substring to join first city and last city in ON condition.

Query:

```
select distinct loc.TransID, dim_FC.LocationID as from_city_id, dim_LC.LocationID as to_city_id from trans_location loc
INNER JOIN dim_location dim_FC ON dim_FC.City = substring(loc.[From City], 1, charindex('/',loc.[From City])-1)
INNER JOIN dim_location dim_LC ON dim_LC.City = reverse(substring(reverse(loc.[To City]),1,charindex('/',REVERSE(loc.[To City]))-1))
order by loc.TransID
```

[image]